# Eclipse - aligning editor view with Makefile

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile

I'm using Eclipse basically only as an editor, not for building my project. This is C Linux project with Makefiles and I run eclipse under Windows (if that matters). I want to see my source code exactly as it would be seen by compiler. E.g. there are preprocessor defines in Makefile and I want them to be reflected in editor - unused #ifdef blocks grayed out.
How can I tell Eclipse to analyze and index my projects according to selected Makefile?